# Group conversation by ID and join the most recent message

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables.

`conversations`

`id | user_from | user_to | subject`

`messages`

`id | user_id | conversation_id | message`

Now I want to pull all conversations for a particular `User`. However, I can't figure how to do this. My current solution gives me the *oldest* message with each conversation.

```
DB::table('conversations')
->where('user_from', '=', $this->id)
->orWhere('user_to', '=', $this->id)
->join('messages', 'conversations.id', '=', 'messages.conversation_id')
->groupBy('conversations.id')
->get();
```

How can I get the *newest* message with each conversation?

Answer (score 0):

In plain Mysql you can use additional self join to messages ,according to your question i guess id from messages table is set to auto_increment so i have used `MAX(id)` to get the recent message id per conversation

```
SELECT 
c.* 
FROM 
conversations c 
JOIN messages m ON(m.conversation_id = c.id)
JOIN  (SELECT conversation_id,MAX(id) ic FROM messages GROUP BY conversation_id) mm
ON(m.conversation_id = mm.conversation_id AND m.id = mm.id)
```